# How can i use rviz to simulate my own robot-model

Tags: simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community
l am new to ros ,i have done many tutorials and read the book about ros ,e.x. ROS By Example.In that book,i do the example  use Arbotix simulator step by step.But i can't understand what happened behind screen.i want  to do something use my own robot-model in rviz.i have built up my robot in urdf . But i don't know what should i do the next.please see my questions below   :

1.how to drive the model built by urdf in rviz

2.if any tutorial exists in ros.org

3.the different between rviz and gazebo ....

my English is not very well ....

i wish i have described my questions clear .

thanks everyone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140926/how-can-i-use-rviz-to-simulate-my-own-robot-model/) by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz is just used for visualization ,gazebo is really used for simulation

---

Originally posted by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) with karma: 63 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0